# Create a plot with twin axes, but with ranges not linked together and with auto-scaling

Tags: bokeh

I've joined to images illustrating my problem:

1. The graph with only one axis and one data series;
2. The graph with both axes (the line at the bottom is the same as the one in the first graph).

I'm using widgets and a Bokeh server in order to have users play with different options showing different data series.

As you can see in the code below, I've used DataRange1d for both ranges, but even though both axes get auto-scaled when I change scenarios using the widgets, the axes stay linked together, covering an identical range no matter what.

I've searched in the docs and the only solution I found to my problem is to pass a specific range to Range1d or DataRange1d. I can't do this since I have many data series to show, so one range wouldn't fit for all.

Thanks!

The code:

```
#create plots
p_balance = figure(width=500, height=300, title='Balance', tools='save')
p_total_debt = figure(width=500, height=300, title='Total debt', tools='save')

p_both = figure(width=1000, height=300, title='Both', tools='save')

#add the second axis
p_both.y_range = DataRange1d()
p_both.extra_y_ranges = {'total debt': DataRange1d()}
p_both.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name='total debt'), 'right')

#add glyphs
line_balance = p_balance.line(x=list(range(0,26)), y='y', source=source_balance, color='black', line_width=2)
line_total_debt = p_total_debt.line(x=list(range(0,26)), y='y', source=source_total_debt, color='black', line_width=2)

#for the second plot with both series
line_balance2 = p_both.line(x=list(range(0,26)), y='y', source=source_balance, color='black', line_width=2)
line_total_debt = p_both.line(x=list(range(0,26)), y='y', source=source_total_debt, color='black', line_width=2, y_range_name='total debt')
```

---

Image 1[image: Image 1]

Image 2[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 1):

It works as soon as you provide some starting values to the Datarange objects...
I the dataranges do not initialize correctly, so it has to be done "manually"

I faked the data since you did not provide any data.  Instead of setting the start and end values explicitly you can use min(your_data) max(your_data).

```
from bokeh.models import DataRange1d, LinearAxis, Range1d
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

# create plots
p_both = figure(width=1000, height=300, title='Both', tools='save',    toolbar_sticky=False)

# add the second axis
p_both.y_range = Range1d(0, 26)
p_both.extra_y_ranges = {'total_debt': Range1d(start=1000, end=1050)}

# for the second plot with both series
line_balance2 = p_both.line(x=range(0, 26), y=range(0, 26), color='black',     line_width=2)
line_total_debt = p_both.line(x=range(0, 26), y=range(1000 + 0, 1000 + 26),    color='red', line_width=2,
                          y_range_name='total_debt')
p_both.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name='total_debt'), 'right')

show(p_both)
```

[image]